# Send data to a port via linux command

Tags: linux, curl, client-server, client-side, sendmessage

I want to send simple data (say like "hello world") to another system (and to a particular port number) via Linux command. I am looking for a command similar to client program? Can any one help me out?

I was trying with CURL but I am not getting it correctly. If it possible in CUrl can you give some examples?

Thanks in advance

Comment: fair enough. ill delete my comment

Answer (score 5):

The program you're looking for is called "nc".